# jquery change selected option on .ajax appended select fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, selected

I release this question has been asked in many flavours before. But trying most of the answers does not get the result to change the `selected` choice.

We are using ajax to load a .js script and create a select box dynamically that is heavily nested in other elements, all with random id's.

First the outer select is created & appended to the host div,

```
var baseSelect = '<select id="' + randId + '" placeholder="' + PlaceHolderText + '" data-stuff="' + stuffId + '"><option value="' + randId +'_a" selected>alpha</option></select>';
$(baseSelect).appendTo('#' + hostDiv);
```

then the data for the select box is loaded from json, and that is appended to the select element

```
//....create other options....//
$.map(data, function (item) {
     ......
     //create newopts
}
$("#"+randId).append(newopts);
```

this generates the final select box

```
<select id="rnd_1515181630427" class="sel" placeholder="Status-Zulu" data-stuff="zulu">
    <option value="rnd_1515181630427_a" selected>alpha</option>
    <option value="c1">choice 1</option>
    <option value="c2">choice 2</option>
    <option value="c3">choice 3</option>
    <option value="c4">choice 4</option>
</select>
```

In the parent page that loads the *.js with ajax we have a function called after all json is complete,

//Stuff that works

```
var selId = $('[data-fid="'+uuid+'"]').attr('id');
    console.log(selId); // prints rnd_1515181630427 -> correct id
    console.log($('#'+selId).attr("placeholder")); //prints Status-Zulu -> correct
    console.log($('#'+selId+' option:selected').val()); // prints rnd_1515181630427_a -> correct
    console.log($('#'+selId+' option:selected').text()); // prints alpha -> correct
    console.log($('#'+selId+' option[value="'+ selId +'_a"]').text()); // prints alpha -> correct
    console.log($('#'+selId).eq(0).text()); // prints alpha -> correct
```

//Can we change anything in the non appended option?

```
$('#'+selId+' option:selected').text("beta"); //changes selected display text to beta -> correct
console.log($('#'+selId+' option[value="'+ selId +'_a"]').text());// prints beta -> correct
$('#'+selId+' option[value="'+ selId +'_a"]').text("delta"); // changes selected display text to delta -> correct
```

//Can we get anything from an appended option?

```
$('#'+selId+' option[value="c2"]').text("delta"); //not changed
console.log($('#'+selId+' option[value="c2"]').text()); // console is empty ??
console.log($('#'+selId).eq(1).text()); // console empty
```

//other variations that do not work, based on other SO answers

```
$('#'+selId+' option[value=c2]').prop('selected', true);
$('#'+selId+' option[value="c2"]').prop('selected', true);
$('#'+selId+' option[value=c2]').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#'+selId+' option[value="c2"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

What are we doing wrong when the code seems to work on the first `<option>` that is created as part of the `<select>` function, but not on the `<option(s)>` that are appended to the `<select>` object at alatter time?

Comment: Sounds like a  timing issue. Try `console.log($('#'+selId).length)` and try looping over all the options if that works and see what's there when you run the code

Comment: you were right, it looks like it is a timing issue, if we trigger the tests manually after a few seconds, all works as expected. It was the fact we were getting the random id's back and that the json was loaded before the changes were triggered. But the processing of the json must have taken a few microseconds longer than the tests. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: If the code is in different parts of the app could create custom event and trigger it when the options get populated and in listener do whatever it is the other part of app needs to do